# Effective processing with completableFuture mixed workloads

Tags: java, executorservice

I working on a service that will process large number of requests, each in a different file. The challenge is that processing requires both local processing (cpu), and remote (database) processing. Database has Hugh capacity. Database work is 30-80% of processing (Dynamic, can not be calculated up front)

The default commonPool used for completionService.completeAsync uses a pool with (processors-1) threads. Given that large portion of the processing is waiting for database work, the default commonPool underutilize local Machine resources.

I am believe using a custom executor that will conditionally pause if local load on the machine is high can improve situation. Now sure how to build such executor. Any advice ? Any existing library providing such code exists ?

For readers familiar with gnu make - equivalent to make ability to limit concurrent processing based on load.

Comment: A question worth asking: would utilizing more local CPU significantly accelerate the completion of the task? Or would the database be principally determining the completion speed? If job completion won't change much as more "local" jobs finish only to "wait" for database, maybe the change adds no improvement. *Otherwise*, I think you should over-schedule your Java thread pool, especially if the DB can take more concurrent tasks than *processors - 1*, or if in a lot of cases the ratio of the work done by your Java application exceeds a threshold like 0.5 (your assessment, of course).

Comment: The remote database has “infinite” capacity (in memory database). Most of the database “processing” is round trip. The challenge is that the ratio is variable (depending on request type), no easy way to estimate a single ratio that will work for everything. Some requests have lot of local processing, some have nominal local processing. Bottom line, for certain workloads, using more threads will speed up processing significantly (3-4x).

Comment: If I were you, I would over-schedule the Java executor, by a great factor; then I'd meticulously monitor the thread pool to work out a sweet size. The only thing to be careful about is the cost of jobs in the queue. Perhaps this is what led to your question... I'm trying to conceptualize a "pull" pool that tries to maintain a fixed-size queue. Maybe this is not so hard to code yourself (I don't know of any existing implementation.)

Comment: Could you use any of the pools provided by the factories in [`java.util.concurrent.Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)? E.g. `newFixedThreadPool`, `newCachedThreadPool`, or `newWorkStealingPool`? You could then run your futures on your custom pool

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I'll take a shot at answering anyway. So what I understand is you run a large number of requests on a fixed size thread pool, and you find your CPU is underutilized because often times these threads are blocked waiting for a response from the database.

So generally speaking, I think what you want is to prevent your worker threads from being blocked by I/O. Instead of making your thread pool bigger to compensate for blocking I/O, you should use a non-blocking database driver and eliminate blocking I/O altogether.

Different approaches exist for different databases. Some support async I/O natively, some provide the illusion by maintaining a separate thread pool for DB I/O. Some integrate with higher-level abstractions such as [Reactive Streams](https://www.reactive-streams.org).

For [Redis](https://redis.io), for example, there is an alternative Java driver called [Lettuce](https://lettuce.io), that provides an [asynchronous API](https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/index.html#asynchronous-api) and a [reactive API](https://lettuce.io/core/release/reference/index.html#reactive-api). *(Disclaimer: I have not used Lettuce myself.)*

Comment: Using redis as database.

Comment: Thanks for input. The overall system is alreayd built, so I do not have the option of adopting new processing style (async database client) - looking for a way to help me build "ExcecutionService" that will improve throughput for this specific case.